# How to return pointer from linked list (in Class Template)

Tags: c++, list, class, oop, templates

I've stumbled upon a problem with my linked list class.
I've one abstract class `Shape` and multiple classes inheriting from it, like `Square` or `Triangle` etc. 
I'm storing them in my `List` class but I don't know how to return stored object back to the pointer of `Shape`.
Since my explanation may seem pretty vague here is some code with expected behaviour explained.

```
class Shape // abstract class
{
public:
 int a;
//some member virtual methods
};

class Square : public Shape
{
//using the virtual methods from Shape
};
```

In my main file, this is how I want to use it:

```
int main()
{
    List<Shape*> ShapeList;
    Shape *ptr;
    Square a(2, 1, 1); // size, x, y coordinates
    ShapeList.add(ptr);

//up to this point everything works well
// now I want my list to return a pointer to it's member 
// so I can modify it

    Shape *listptr;
        listptr = ShapeList.findInstanceAt(0); // here's my error

    listptr->a = 5; // what I want to do next
}
```

So as you can see I'm havingtroubles with returning proper value from my list and I don't know how to solve this.

Here's my simplified list implementation:

```
template <class T> class Node
{
            T data; 
            Node *next; 

    public:             

            inline T getData()
            {
                return data;
            }

            inline Node* getNext()
            {
                return next;
            }
};
```

```
template <class T> class List
{
    Node<T> *head, *tail;

public:

    List() : head(NULL), tail(NULL) { }

    T* findInstanceAt(int _k)
    {
        if (NULL == head)
        {
            cout << "\nList is empty.";
            return NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            Node<T> *temp = new Node<T>;
            temp = head;

            for (size_t k = 0; k < _k; ++k)
            {
                if (NULL != temp->getNext()) temp = temp->getNext();
                else return NULL;
            }

            return temp->getData;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on how to make this work.

@EDIT
Ahh I forgot to add compiler errors that I'm getting:

```
Error   1   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'Shape **' to 'Shape *'
```

Comment: *"So as you can see I'm having some troubles with returning proper value from my list"* -- No, we can't see that. What happens? What do you expect to happen instead? Do you get compiler errors? If so, what are they and on what line?

Comment: Also... `Node<T> *temp = new Node<T>; temp = head;` ... Why do you allocate a new `Node<T>` object on the heap and then immediately clobber the pointer with a different pointer? You're just leaking memory here and you don't even need to allocate a new object in the first place; presumably you wanted `Node<T> *temp = head;`.

Comment: And (finally) why aren't you just using `std::list`? ;)

Comment: Not the answer, but remove `Node<T> *temp = new Node<T>;` that's useless and creates nothing more than a memory leak.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add my compiler error, now I've edited the post.
@cdhowie I cannot use std::list even though it would be great.

Comment: What is `ShapeList`? If it's some `List<Shape*>` then `T*` becomes `Shape**` (as suggested by the compiler error) which isn't at all what you want. Perhaps you wanted a `List<Shape>` instead.

Comment: Thats exactly what it is. Oh and thanks for letting me know where I have my leak, I was actually aware that I'm leaking it but now I realized where it is happening.

Comment: Thank you @cdhowie based on your comment and pm100's I was able to solve this. As you suggested, I've stayed with my List<Shape*> because I'm needed to, but your comment about how T* becomes Shape** pointed me in the right direction. I think case is solved : ). (And no memory leaks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to store Shapes or pointers to Shapes in the list? And do you want the findInstanceAt to return the node in the list or a pointer to the node in the list? At the moment you are not consistent on these things

You store Shape* nodes in the list but the findInstanceAt returns a pointer to the node - which is a Shape** object. This is what the compiler is complaining about

You probaly need to chang

```
T* findInstanceAt(int _k)
```

to

```
T findInstanceAt(int _k)
```

Comment: I changed it and now I'm getting this:
'return' : cannot convert from 'Shape (__thiscall Node<T>::* )(void)' to 'Shape *'

Comment: I want my list to store pointers to Shapes and unfortunately I'm now sure how to answer the second question :(

Comment: Nevermind! I forgot to add parentheses after my getData call : ).

Comment: @capybara It might actually be better to return `T&` instead, so that the object in the list can be modified directly, if desired. You could also take a pointer to it this way. (`Node<T>::getData()` would need to be modified to return `T&` as well.)